# F#: How to represent a finite collection with strong typing?

Tags: collections, f#, strong-typing

I have a finite set of things all of the same type, and I wish to represent them in a strongly-typed way. I'd like to be able to manipulate the complete set and easily extract the elements. Here is one way:

```
type Planet = Mercury | Venus | Earth
type PlanetInfo = { Diameter: float }
let planets =
    Map [ Mercury, { Diameter = 100. }
          Venus, { Diameter = 200. }
          Earth, { Diameter = 300. } ]
let venusDiameter = planets.[Venus].Diameter
```

The good points about this method are:

1. There are exactly three `Planet`s, as defined by the discriminated union.
2. We have the whole set in the map `planets`, which can be manipulated, iterated etc..
3. `planets.[Mars]` would cause an error, because "Mars" is not a `Planet`.

But on the downside:

4. There is not necessarily a one-to-one mapping between the union and the map. The need to mention each planet twice is a shortcoming. Here is another method which addresses the last point:

```
type Planet = { Name: string; Diameter: float }
let planets =
    [ { Name = "Mercury"; Diameter = 100. }
      { Name = "Venus"; Diameter = 200. }
      { Name = "Earth"; Diameter = 300. } ]
    |> List.map (fun e -> e.Name, e)
    |> Map
let venusDiameter = planets.["Venus"].Diameter
```

So now each planet is mentioned in only one place, but `planets.["Mars"]` fails to cause a compile-time error because the planet identifiers are now "stringly typed".

Is there some way of doing this which has all four good points?

Comment: To start with, use a function with match instead of a map.

Comment: @BentTranberg Wouldn't that frustrate goal number 2?

Comment: Maybe. In my opinion code should not be written like this - with the data itself expressed as types. Also, needing reflection for an isolated piece of logic is a sign of bad architecture. These two problems go together.

Comment: Sometimes the distinction between data and types is not so simple. You can always abstract things to be more and more generic and have the specifics be some data that is loaded at runtime. You lose some compile time guarantees, and lose some simplicity, but you might gain in being able to represent a wider domain. You need to evaluate this tradeoff in each situation.

Comment: In this case, if the app is specifically concerned with the planets orbiting Sol, then I don't see much benefit in representing the planets as data. But if the app was concerned with orbiting bodies around any celestial object, then it would have to be data. If you are sure the domain will always be planets around Sol, then why complicate matters? But if this app might need to be extended in future then it is probably better to generalize now, than trying to generalize a completed project later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
type Planet =
    |Mercury
    |Venus
    |Earth
    member this.Diameter =
        match this with
        |Mercury -> 100.
        |Venus -> 200.
        |Earth -> 300.

open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection
let planets =
    FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<Planet>)
    |> Array.map (fun case -> FSharpValue.MakeUnion(case, [||]) :?> Planet)
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid reflection, but if no better answer appears soon, I'll accept this one. Despite its verbosity it does satisfy my four desiderata.

Comment: If you need to enumerate multiple unions like this, you can always create a generic helper function to do it. Just replace `Planet` with `'T`.

Comment: Great idea; thanks for the helpful answer and comment.

Comment: I second this approach, but.. There isn't really even a need for the map at this point. If you have the planet, you already have the diameter. The map adds no value at that point.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to use the Planet type as the Name member in the PlanetInfo type and initialize the Map using a transformation from list:

```
module Planets =
    type Planet = 
    | Mercury
    | Venus
    | Earth

    type PlanetInfo = { Name: Planet; Diameter: float}

    let planets : PlanetInfo list = 
        [
            {Name = Mercury; Diameter = 100.}
            {Name = Venus; Diameter = 200.}
            {Name = Earth; Diameter = 300.}
        ]

    let planetsmap = planets |> List.map (fun pi -> pi.Name, pi) |> Map.ofList 

    
    planetsmap.[Mercury].Diameter
```

This approach doesn't require reflection and offers compile time type checking. So it is pretty much the same as your second approach, Monica.

Comment: A worthy submission @Piotr, but I believe it is more similar to my first approach: there is no compile-time enforcement of correspondence between the union and the map. i.e. One could delete an element from the map.

Comment: Just add a unit test to catch the potential problem, and then this will be a nice solution.